# Oracle RECORDS and table of records type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a record type defined with two fields.

```
TYPE record is RECORD (
 a NUMBER,
  b VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

and I have defined a type which is a table of above record type mentioned.

```
TYPE recordTable is TABLE of record;
```

I declare a variable in the script

```
recordVar recordTable;
```

In plsql script I successfully populate variable `recordVar` declared above with some values.

Post this I want to join `recordVar` with one of the existing table.

How do I achieve this??

If I do a `select * from recordVar`. I get an error saying table or view doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, a `RECORD` is a PL/SQL data type and cannot be used in SQL statements.

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE recordType is RECORD ( a NUMBER, b VARCHAR2(20) );
  TYPE recordTable is TABLE of recordType;
  
  v_recs recordTable;
BEGIN
  v_recs.EXTEND(2);
  v_recs(1).a := 23;
  v_recs(1).b := 'ABC';
  v_recs(2).a := 42;
  v_recs(2).b := 'DEF';
  
  FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_recs))
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.a || ', ' || i.b);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs the errors:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 13, column 33:
> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
> ORA-06550: line 13, column 27:
> PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
> ORA-06550: line 13, column 13:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> ```

---

If you want to do something similar, then declare it as an `OBJECT` in the SQL scope:

```sql
CREATE TYPE objectType is OBJECT( a NUMBER, b VARCHAR2(20) );
CREATE TYPE objectTable is TABLE of objectType;
```

Then you can use it in PL/SQL and SQL via a table collection expression:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_objs objectTable := objectTable();
BEGIN
  v_objs.EXTEND(2);
  v_objs(1) := objectType(23, 'ABC');
  v_objs(2) := objectType(42, 'DEF');

  FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_objs))
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.a || ', ' || i.b);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 23, ABC
> 42, DEF
> ```

---

Then, if you want to join it with another table you can do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 23, 'UVW' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 42, 'XYZ' FROM DUAL;
```

```sql
DECLARE
  v_objs objectTable := objectTable();
BEGIN
  v_objs.EXTEND(2);
  v_objs(1) := objectType(23, 'ABC');
  v_objs(2) := objectType(42, 'DEF');

  FOR i IN (SELECT o.a, o.b, t.value
            FROM   TABLE(v_objs) o
                   INNER JOIN table_name t
                   ON o.a = t.id)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.a || ', ' || i.b || ', ' || i.value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 23, ABC, UVW
> 42, DEF, XYZ
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=abadb498281f4373114cf1e3716c0800)*